# Getting error when running flutter command

Tags: flutter, command-line

I have the following issue and dont know what to do.

Everytime when I run the following command, I get the following error:

```
PS D:\Programming\Flutter\Learn\Riverpod\to_do_app> flutter clean
Checking Dart SDK version... 
"<<" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.
```

It does not metter where I run the command, the output is everytime the same.
I also can run:

```
C:\Users\user>flutter doctor
Checking Dart SDK version...
"<<" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.
```

The issue came today the first time as I run the "flutter clean" command. Yesterday, everything works correctly. It also only cames by Flutter commands. When I run a Python command or else it works normally.

My Dart sdk version is the newest:

```
dart-sdk v2.18.0 is the latest version available based on your source(s).
```

I dont know why this happen. But I want to fix this imediatly.
Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution now. I just had to go into the Flutter folder (installation folder) and run the following command.

```
git reset --hard
```

Now everything works fine.